# Handle Spring data source being temporarily unavailable during Hibernate initialisation

Tags: spring, hibernate

Part of my Spring (4.3.23) / Hibernate (5.0.12) application "A" uses a data source that is exposed be a second application "B" (the data source is an in-memory database). Both A and B are deployed in Tomcat and I don't control start order. Once both A and B have started both behave as expected, however if A starts before B an error is thrown during initialisation when Hibernate tries to query the data source:

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator - HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Connection is broken: "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: 127.0.1.1:5521" [90067-199])
```

Is there any way I can suppress this error, delay this part of initialisation, or tell Hibernate that the data source may not be immediately available?

Here are the relevant parts of my configuration:

```
<bean id="memDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
  <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/memdb" />
</bean>

<bean
  id="memSessionFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="memDataSource" />
  <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.company" />
  <property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
      <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
      </props>
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="memTransactionManager"class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="memSessionFactory" />
  <qualifier value="memTransactions"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="memTransactionManager" />
```

Comment: Can you please share MCVE? Share MCVE for application A and B to reproduce this issue https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What connection pool implementation are you using? If you can switch to Hikari, it supports initializationFailTimeout which could be just what you need

Answer (score 0):

I would wind up scripting the deployment overall.  Bring up tomcat with application A in the webapps directory, and periodically ping for successful deployment of application A before copying/moving over application B into the webapps directory for deployment.

This entire solution would likely work best if you used a staging directory to move your war files onto that server, and then let the script clear the webapps directory and move/copy the new war(s) into webapps for fresh deployment.

SideNote: I've found that deployment of applications seems to be in a constant order, but I'm not sure as it is alphabetical, oldest first, or something else.